# OpenSSL - Create private key doesn't prompt password

Tags: passwords, openssl, private-key

I installed OpenSSL 1.1.1 on windows https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705#Download-OpenSSL

When I create private key I don't get password prompt

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out PrivKey.pem 2048
```

Output:

```
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
```

I'm expecting password prompt, I don't remember adding/choosing password before.

How should I be prompt password when creating private key?

Comment: A bug?  This should prompt.  An alternative Windows version from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html does prompt.

Comment: @garethTheRed when downloaded the linux version it works

Answer (score 0):

In this answer there is a working solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275008/in-git-bash-windows-openssl-pkcs12-does-not-prompt-for-password#answer-72652625

put "winpty" before your command

winpty bash script.sh ......

winpty openssl .....

Comment: If there is a valid answer to another question, mark this one as duplicate.

Comment: @Toto I can't do it, I think I don't have the reputation needed